# How to Update SSL ciphers suites

Tags: ssl

I have a site. I bought SSL certificate for that site. I am getting below message when I click on Padlock Icon.

[image]

I would like to display "**using an modern cipher suite**" instead of "**using an obsolete cipher suite**" in above image.

How can I do that ??

(Actually I am new in SSL. I know little about SSL and cipher suite. I think I failed to express it properly.)

Comment: this previous Q&A may help: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph

Comment: Thanks @khakiout for your reply. I read that Q&A. But I looking for step by step guide to update SSL cipher suite. Could you please help me in this regard ?? Thanks.

Comment: What web server are you running?

Comment: Thanks @AnandBhat for your reply. I am using Apache Server with Linux OS. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Head over to the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/), select your version of Apache and OpenSSL and specify your profile as "Intermediate" (for maximum compatibility). Disable HSTS until you know what it is.

Copy the directives SSLProtocol, SSLCipherSuite and SSLHonorCipherOrder and place them in your Apache configuration file.

For example:

```
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
```

Comment: Thanks @Anand Bhat for your reply. I need a step by step guide. I am trying to modify .htaccess file using your solution. Thanks